# Using array values to assign button labels in HTML

Tags: html, button, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create an add-on on for gSheets to display a sidebar or dialog with a dynamic number of buttons derived from text in a cell which has been clicked on.

There is a varying number of words in the cells of the target column. The objective is to load the words into a single-dimensional array and use each word as the label of a button. Then by clicking on a button, the same text appearing as the button label is copied to the clipboard.

I've successfully gotten the contents of a selected cell to load into an array as follows (the target strings are delimited by a period):

```
  function splitText() {
     var array1 = [{}];
     var string1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue();

     array1 = string1.split('. ');

     for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
        array1[i] = '\\n'+'\\n'+array1[i];
     }
```

Including custom buttons in a sidebar requires referencing an HTML file which I'm doing as follows:

```
function openSidebar(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Sidebar').setTitle('Text Copy Buttons');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

I'm familiar with the basic HTML to create a button as follows:

```
<body>
    <button onclick='myFunction()' id='button1'>LABEL TO BE ASSIGNED</button>
</body>
```

I'd like to know how to create a variable number of buttons by looping through the array and assigning each array value to a new button label. Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try jQuery:

#### Flow:

- Serve basic HTML  with buttons inside a `div`
- On Window Load run `splitText` function on server side with `google.script.run`
- Receive the array from `splitText` and update `div` with jQuery `append`
- Alternatively, You can directly use Templated HTML to do a for-loop to append.

#### Index.html:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showButtons)
        .splitText()
    });

function showButtons(arr){
  var b = $('#buttons');
  b.empty();
  for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    b.append("<button onclick='myFunction()' id='button"+i+"'>"+arr[i]+"</button>")
  }
}
  </script>  
</head>  

<body>
  <div id ="buttons">
    <button onclick='myFunction()' id='button'>LABEL TO BE ASSIGNED</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### Code.gs:

```
function splitText() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue()
  .toString()
  .split('. ');
  }
```

#### References:

- [TemplatedHTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates)
- [jQuery vs Template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates)